# How to use Math.Abs inside my own generic method?

Tags: c#

The following code does not compile with

> ... cannot convert T to int  bla bla bla

```
bool IsEqual<T>(this T a, T b, T offset)
{
    a = Math.Abs(a);
    b = Math.Abs(b);
    if (Math.Abs(a - b) < offset)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How to use `Math.Abs` inside my own generic method?

Comment: You can't. You'll need to just provide a set of overloads and some very repetitive code for the types that `Math.Abs` actually supports (or the smaller subset of types that you want to work with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only .Net had *class* or *interface* like **Number** in *Java*, you could well have put something like

```
 // Doesn't compile; just the idea
 bool IsEqual<T>(this T a, T b, T offset) 
   where T: Number { // <- T can be any integer or floating point type 
     a = Math.Abs(a);
     ....
```

Unfortunately, .Net *doesn't provide* such an interface and so you have to implement *overload versions* of `IsEqual`:

```
  bool IsEqual(this Double a, Double b, Double offset) {
    return (Math.Abs(a - b) < offset);
  }

  bool IsEqual(this Single a, Single b, Single offset) {
    return (Math.Abs(a - b) < offset); 
  }

  bool IsEqual(this long a, long b, long offset) {
    return (Math.Abs(a - b) < offset);
  }

  bool IsEqual(this int a, int b, int offset) {
    return (Math.Abs(a - b) < offset);
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. In your method the type parameter `T` could be anything, a string, a class, you name it.

`Math.Abs` exists only for a small set of parameter types. It would be nice if you could constraint `T` to them, but that's not possible either.

That means if you need the `IsEqual` method to work with different types of `T` you will have to write the overloads for them manually:

```
bool IsEquals(int a, int b, int offset) { }
bool IsEquals(double a, double b, double offset) { }
// and many more
```

Comment: can we use extension method here?

Comment: You can make them extension methods of course, but that won't solve the problem.

Comment: @TheLastError the problem is that whether you use extension methods or not you will have to constraint T to something or Math.Abs(a) won't compile, but that constraint is simply not possible because the C# spec won't allow it. And the constraint would also have to include that an `operator -` exists on `T`.